# How to compare two columns in pandas, with only part of codes?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python3 and pandas I have two dataframes, "doacoes_cnpjs" and "te"

```
doacoes_cnpjs.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 22811 entries, 0 to 47353
Data columns (total 19 columns):
UF                                22811 non-null object
Partido_x                         22811 non-null object
Cargo_x                           22811 non-null object
Nome_candidato_x                  22811 non-null object
CPF_candidato                     22811 non-null int64
CPF_CNPJ_doador                   22811 non-null float64
Nome_doador                       22811 non-null object
Nome_doador_Receita               22811 non-null object
Valor                             22811 non-null float64
CPF_CNPJ_doador_originario        22811 non-null object
Nome_doador_originario            22811 non-null object
Nome_doador_originario_Receita    22811 non-null object
Estado                            22811 non-null object
Cargo_y                           22811 non-null object
Nome_candidato_y                  22811 non-null object
CPF                               22811 non-null int64
Nome_urna                         22811 non-null object
Partido_y                         22811 non-null object
Situacao                          22811 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(15)
memory usage: 3.5+ MB


te.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5541 entries, 0 to 5664
Data columns (total 13 columns):
DATA_LS               4118 non-null object
DATA_INCLUS           2957 non-null object
Proprietario          5541 non-null object
Nome_propriedade      5541 non-null object
Municipio             5525 non-null object
Estado                5533 non-null object
CNPJ_CPF_CEI          5541 non-null object
CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo    5541 non-null float64
Trab_Envolv           4529 non-null float64
Ramo_atividade        2840 non-null object
Localizacao           2734 non-null object
Cod_ativ              2975 non-null object
Tipo_lista            5541 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), object(11)
memory usage: 606.0+ KB
```

Dataframes have two columns with the same type of code - "CPF_CNPJ_doador" and "CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo". They are codes with integers, with 13 or 14 digits
Example: "6158959000136", "78141843000103", "46991295000106", "5351494000172" ...

I want to create a new dataframe from a comparison of "doacoes_cnpjs" and "te", using the columns "CPF_CNPJ_doador" and "CNPJ_CPF_CEI_limpo". But it can not be a common merge

I want to compare only the first eight numbers of the columns. Example: from "6158959000136" only use "61589590" and compare with "78141843" from code "78141843000103", and thus on all lines

Please, is there a way to do this? Or is it best to turn the codes into strings and before extracting the first few characters?

Comment: Do you mind to write a small example? It's not clear to me what you want to compare.

Comment: Why is the comparision required?

Comment: Thank you. What I need to compare are federal business registration codes. Always the first eight codes are the "root number". The remaining numbers are the subsidiaries

Comment: So if I compare only the first eight numbers I will know which business group are in the two dataframes, regardless of which branch is

Comment: To get first 8 digits you can do a string operation i.e `df['CPF_CNPJ_doador'].astype(str).str[:8]`, store it it new column if you want then do group, merge whatever you would like to do.

Comment: I think it would be best to break down into a simpler example what you are trying to do and work with that. Then, if you still have problems with that simple example, post your simpler example as an edit to this question post.